# Showing the name of the current background color of a Form

Tags: c#, background-color

I change the color of my form by using:

```
private void menuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Now, I would like to show what background color is selected for my form in `label1`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = /*????????????*/;
}
```

What should I write in the bottom to achieve this?

Comment: What would you expect the label to read, FF0000 (hex colour), "Red" (colour name) - or something else?

Comment: Come on, this was a question? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get color as string then use this:

```
label1.Text = this.BackColor.ToString(); // Green
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label1.Text = this.BackColor.ToString();
```